# $routeProvider issues with Google App Engine, stuck in infinite loop and crashing browser

Tags: google-app-engine, angularjs

I'm in the process of moving our application to Angular, this is what my routes look like for my app, pretty straightforward. When Angular grabs `home.html` to insert into `ng-view` Chrome gets stuck in an infinite loop reloading the page until it finally crashes. This is occurring in Google App Engine, however the same code ran on WAMP works perfectly fine.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : "home.html",
            controller  : "mainController"
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : "about.html",
            controller  : "mainController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl : "home.html",
            controller  : "aboutController"
        });
});
```

app.yaml

```
application: activity-tracking
version: dev
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:

- url: /web/components
  static_dir: web/components

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- deferred: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

My best guess is that I need to have App Engine ignore requests from Angular to get a file and only ever serve up `index.html` which will Angular will inject into. Which it's currently not doing resulting in my infinite loop to go to `/home.html` and then redirecting back to `/index.html` etc.

Comment: added, minus the unrelated handlers

Comment: I think you are missing your root handler. and the app to display it.

Comment: can your provide any guidance on that? I'm not to familiar with GAE

Comment: My otherwise looks more like this:

    .otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
    });

Comment: Unfortunately my problem is with GAE configuration not really the `$routeProvider` which is working, it just drops me into an infinite loop of requesting `home.html` then back to `index.html` then back to `home.html` etc until the browser crashes. On WAMP the same code works perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution which was rather simple should anyone else stumble upon this. I was originally including my html partials in the /web directory which the backend was also picking up and trying to do the routing for and direct me to that html file.

Moved my partials to /static so that the backend wasn't trying to route to that html file when Angular was fetching the file and doing it's injection.